# Site to find no popular papers/books

Tags: soft-question

I'm studying this [article](http://gdz-lucene.tc.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gcs/gcs?&action=pdf&metsFile=PPN365956996_0061&divID=LOG_0020&pagesize=original&pdfTitlePage=http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/pdftitle/?metsFile=PPN365956996_0061%7C&targetFileName=PPN365956996_0061_LOG_0020.pdf&) and in a particular proof the author advices to look for this paper/book:

> Buchweitz,R.-O.: Über Deformationem monomialer Kurvensingularitäten
>   und Weierstrasspunkte auf Riemannschen Flächen.

Is there some site which I can buy this material? I really need this to understand the article I'm reading, is it possible to get this material without go to a Germany library?

Thanks

Comment: If something is indexed on a website, certainly it's known to someone. Therefore there is no website to find unknown books and papers. $\square$

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes, by "unknown" I meant "no popular".

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0085884.

Comment: @PhoemueX it was not very helpful, thank you very much for trying to help me!

Comment: You should consider writing an email to the University of Hanover in Germany. As this was Buchweitz's PhD thesis, it is somewhat unlikely that it was published under this name, but instead was published in some other form under some other name(s). You might also consider sending an email to F Torres, who seems to have a copy, and might be more prone to giving one to you.

Comment: @mixedmath How do you know F. Torres has a copy? thank you

Comment: @mixedmath do you think University of Hanover could give me this paper?